# I am trying to make a multi machine node to run service fabric...but getting error

Tags: cluster-computing, azure-service-fabric

Running Best Practices Analyzer...
Unable to change open service manager handle because 5
Unable to query service configuration because System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to change open service manager ha
ndle because 5
   at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.FabricDeployerServiceController.GetServiceStartupType(String machineName, String serv
iceName)
Querying remote registry service on machine machine1 resulted in exception: Unable to change open service manager handle
 because 5.